# Two different Google Maps on one page, but only one of them is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have added two different Google Maps with different Latitude and Longtitude for each map, but only one of the maps are showing on the front-end.

I'm not very good with JavaScript, but I assume that the `initMap` functions has to be created into one function, since right now there are two `initMap` functions and i think this is causing the problem, if i'm not fully wrong here.

Javascript:

```
<script>
  // You can set control options to change the default position or style of many
  // of the map controls.

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('osloAirport'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: {lat: 60.21048, lng: 11.06702},
      mapTypeControl: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      draggable: !("ontouchend" in document),    

      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
        mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain']
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<script>
  // You can set control options to change the default position or style of many
  // of the map controls.

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('torpAirport'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: {lat: 59.18245, lng: 10.25691},
      mapTypeControl: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      draggable: !("ontouchend" in document),    

      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
        mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain']
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <!--<img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="img/team/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">-->
            <div id="osloAirport" style="width:auto;height:265px;margin-top: 20px;"></div>
            <div class="airports">
                <h4 class="service-heading"><span>Oslo</span> Airport</h4>
                <p class="service-second-heading">Dummy text</p>
                <p class="text-muted">This is just dummy text</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <!--<img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="img/team/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">-->
            <div id="torpAirport" style="width:auto;height:265px;margin-top: 20px;"></div>                
            <div class="airports">                                
                <h4 class="service-heading"><span>Sandefjord Torp</span> Airport</h4>
                <p class="service-second-heading">Dummy text</p>
                <p class="text-muted">This is just dummy text.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using only one function. I am guessing there is a warning in the console telling you that you're trying to redeclare function initMap.

Comment: Correct, I get this error `InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function`. Are you able to show me how i can make this into one function? I would appreciate it!

Comment: You could rename both functions initOsloMap and initTorpMap, then create this function : function initMap () {initOsloMap(); initTorpMap();}

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of one of the Functions you are declaring a function as a global variable then reseting it's value to a new map , all you have to do it to rename one of them for example name the second function initmap2